# I am trying to Copy row 2 in sheet 1 and paste it into sheet 2 on the next empty row.

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Copy row 2 in sheet 1 and paste it into sheet 2 on the next empty row. 
I then change the data in row 2 and run the macro again to add this data on the next row of sheet 2.

This is what i have, but it writes over the data in sheet 2:

```
Sub transfer()

Dim LastRow As Integer

'Where is the last cell with data?
LastRow = Worksheets("Database").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Transfer data
Sheets("Shadow").Range("A2:N2").Copy Worksheets("Database").Cells(LastRow + 1, "A")
End Sub
```

Comment: Data in the destination sheet will only get over-written if there are blank cells in ColA for the last-copied rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Shadow" is Sheet1 and "Database" is Sheet2, this seems to work for me.

#### Edit

Based on our conversation below, if the problem is about references, you can always paste the exact value instead of the reference.  Try this:

```
Sub transfer()

Dim LastRow As Integer

'Where is the last cell with data?
LastRow = Worksheets("Database").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

'Transfer data
Sheets("Shadow").Range("A2:N2").Copy
Worksheets("Database").Range("A" & LastRow + 1 & ":N" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: it works once. Then when i try to run it again after clear row 2 in sheet 1. it writes over the old data

Comment: When I run this, it's not overwriting any data. If I put values on row 2 in Sheet1, this Sub pastes them into the first empty row of Sheet2. If I run it several times, it still copies the data into the next unused row.  Nothing is overwritten.

Comment: what if the cells have references in them? they are referenceing different cells.

Comment: you are right if i just enter data in the cells then it works

Comment: but row 2 sheet one is pulling data from another sheet

Comment: See my Edit above.  Does that help?